# $g\circ f$ and $h\circ g$ are bijective, how can we Prove that $f, g$ and $h$ are bijective?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

if $X,Y,Z$ and $T$ be sets
$f$ be a map from $X$ to $Y$
$g$ a map from $Y$ to $Z$ 
$h$ a map from $Z$ to $T$
$g\circ f$ and $h\circ g$ are bijective

how can we Prove that $f,g$ and $h$ are bijective?

Answer (score 2):

Since $gf$ is surjective, $g$ is surjective. Since $hg$ is injective, $g$ is injective. We thus see that $g$ is bijective.

In particular, $g$ has an inverse function. Now $f=g^{-1}\circ gf$, being the composition of bijective functions is bijective. Etc.